# Prove that $\{ f \in \mathbb{R}^{[0,1]} : \sup_{t \in [0,1]} f(t) < 1 \}$ is not measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ be the set of all functions $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$. The infinite dimensisonal product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{T}([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ is generated by the cylindrical sets:
$$
\{f \in \mathbb{R}^{[0,1]} : f(t_1) \in I_1, \ldots, f(t_n) \in I_n\}
$$
with $I_i$ being subintervals of $\mathbb{R}$. How may I go about proving that the following set is not measurable with respect to $\mathcal{T}([0,1], \mathbb{R})$:
$$
\{f \in \mathbb{R}^{[0,1]} : \sup_{t \in [0,1]} f(t) < 1\}.
$$

This is an exercise from the textbook "Diffusion Processes and Stochastic Calculus" by Fabrice Baudoin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The product $\sigma$-algebra should enjoy the following property that I like to call "determined by countably many values". More precisely,

**Prop**: For any set $A$ in the product $\sigma$-algebra, there exists a countable set of indices $I \subset [0,1]$, and a family $F$ of functions in $\mathbb{R}^I$, such that $f \in A$ iff $f|_I$ lies in $F$.

To prove the proposition, one can check that the function with this property forms a $\sigma$-algebra, and all the generators of the product $\sigma$-algebra has this property.

Now it remains to check that the set $\{f \in \mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}: \sup f < 1\}$ does not have this property, which is quite straightforward.